# Magento 2 | Remove telephone from checkout address

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, address

How can I remove the telephone field from the address fields in checkout (without CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily, we should try with below code:

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

For example, in  `app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme}/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`, find the component that you need to customize. Copy the corresponding node and all parent nodes up to . We're going to remove/disable telephone and telephone fields:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!--Remove fields-->
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Don't forgot to `Run php bin/magento c:c` & `php bin/magento c:f`

Answer (score 1):

In **`checkout_index_index.xml`** file find below code:

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions.</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

and add below line

```
<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

after doing changes please clear cache running

> php bin/magento cache:flush

and also clear your browser's cache and cookie.