# Magento 2.3.3 - How to remove city field from shipping address and billing address from checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

I want to remove city field from both shipping address and billing address on checkout page. I did manage to remove them using them `checkout_index_index.xml` but getting error **"City is required field"**.

Do anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245163/20064 check this answer, it shows how to remove telephone ,you can try same approach

Comment: @Nayem can you give solution to remove city in checkout

Comment: @Pawankumar you cannot really remove city field. But what can be be done is hiding the field and set a value using js. I am little busy today if you need i can provide detailed answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Nayem can you please provide i will try today thank you